# Matrices containing elements which are polynomials or rational functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, representation-theory, rational-functions

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897149/multiplication-of-rational-matrices/1897177#1897177). I am aware of the connection of

1. polynomial multiplication and convolution of coefficients.
2. convolution and multiplication by circulant matrix.

These two ought to be combined to represent multiplication of polynomials with matrix multiplication (or am I mistaken?) But how could one do the same with a rational function? Would it for some magical reason be convertible to matrix division?

---

**Edit** Own attempts so far:

If we instead of [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) matrices which represent [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) we work with [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrices which represent zero-padded convolution and let $1+\frac{x}{2}$ be represented by:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&0.5&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0.5&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0.5&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0.5&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0.5\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$
I hope you can see which coefficients go where. The inverse of the above matrix is:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&-0.5&0.25&-0.125&0.0625&-0.03125\\
0&1&-0.5&0.25&-0.125&0.0625\\
0&0&1&-0.5&0.25&-0.125\\
0&0&0&1&-0.5&0.25\\
0&0&0&0&1&-0.5\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$

Which we can see is a geometric series. The inverse of the polynomial is $\frac{1}{1+x/2}$. If we subtract 1, we get: $\frac{1}{1+x/2}-\frac{1}{1}=\frac{1-1-x/2}{1+x/2}$ which is the inverse of $\frac{1+x/2}{x/2}$

Here we will see a minor inconvenience: The matrix is nilpotent - and can not have an inverse. The same is true for the $x$ polynomial. We can find a pseudo-inverse, but we will lack a last column - the coefficient for the highest power. This we will need to deal with somehow, but let's forget it for a moment and get back to the counter example.

We try to limit ourselves to ${\mathbb R}^{4\times 4}$, with the $p(x)=1+x$ represented according to above, our $\bf A,B$ matrices become:

$${\bf A}=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}1&0&0&0&1&-1&1&-1\\0&1&0&0&0&1&-1&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\\hline 0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right], {\bf B} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\\hline 1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

We can verify that it can handle the calculations $\bf AB, BA$:

$${\bf AB} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}2&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&2&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&2&0&0&0&1\\\hline 1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right] \text{ which is indeed  } \left[\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\p(x)&0\end{array}\right] \text{ , and }$$
$${\bf BA} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}1&0&0&0&2&-1&1&-1\\0&1&0&0&0&2&-1&1\\0&0&1&0&0&0&2&-1\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&2\\\hline 1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right] \text{which is} \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1+1/p(x)\\p(x)&1\end{array}\right]$$

But this still does not prove this would work in a general case, or how to identify a rational function from it's representation once we have done a series of operations on it.

---

**EDIT**

The above observation with geometric series allows us to write as a polynomial of a matrix.

$${\bf P}^{-1} = \sum_i^{\infty} ({\bf I-P})^i$$

So assuming our known matrix $\bf R$ representing some unidentified rational function can be written like ${\bf R}={\bf P}^{-1}{\bf Q}$, we can try to find $\bf P$ and $\bf Q$ by solving for them as such a matrix polynomial times a matrix. Any ideas of how to do that?